# Adding # in inserting dates in php is not working

Tags: php, ms-access

I've been reading a lot about inserting date in MS Access through PHP. However, based on their suggestions, I must use # in inserting dates. However, # in PHP is use to comment out a line of code. My problem right now is, I'm not able to insert/update my dates on my database.

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    $blnPage = $_SESSION['blnCount'];

    try{
        if ($blnPage == "EAP"){
            if (isset($_POST['AudPlanNo']) && !empty($_POST['AudPlanNo'])){

                $txtAPNo = trim($_POST['AudPlanNo']);
                $txtAPUnivNo = trim($_POST['AudUnivNo']);
                $txtAPBackground = trim($_POST['APBackground']);
                $txtAPCoverage = trim($_POST['APCoverage']);
                $txtAPObjective = trim($_POST['APObjective']);
                $txtAPMethodology = trim($_POST['APMethodology']);
                $txtAPWTManhours = trim($_POST['APWTManhours']);
                $txtAPWTDate2 = strtotime($_POST['dWTDate']);
                $txtAPWTDate = date("m-d-Y",$txtAPWTDate2);
                $txtAPFWManhours = trim($_POST['APFWManhours']);
                $txtAPFWDate2 = strtotime($_POST['dFWTDate']);
                $txtAPFWDate = date("m-d-Y",$txtAPFDate2);
                $txtAPRTManhours = trim($_POST['APRTManhours']);
                $txtAPRTDate2 = strtotime($_POST['dRTDate']);
                $txtAPRTDate = date("m-d-Y", $txtAPRTDate2);

                $dbPath = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/msaccess/dbAMS.accdb";
                if(!file_exists($dbPath))
                {
                    die("database not found");
                }
                $dbh = new PDO("odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}; Dbq=$dbPath; Uid=Admin; pwd=;");

                $sql = "UPDATE tblAudPlan SET tblAudPlan.[Background] = '$txtAPBackground', tblAudPlan.[AudObjective] = '$txtAPObjective', tblAudPlan.[AudCoverage] = '$txtAPCoverage', tblAudPlan.[ApproachMethodology] = '$txtAPMethodology', tblAudPlan.[WTManhours] = '$txtAPWTManhours',tblAudPlan.[WTDate] = '#$txtAPWTDate#' WHERE tblAudPlan.[AudPlanNo] = '$txtAPNo'";
                $result = $dbh->query($sql);
                $row = $result->fetch();
                echo 1;   
            }
            else{
                echo 0;
            }
        }

    }

    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
    $dbh = null;
?>
```

And this is how I display my code

```
<div class="col-75">
<input type="date" placeholder = "YYYY-mm-dd" class ="dWTDate" id="dWTDate" name="dWTDate" value="<?php $datetime1 = $_SESSION['sesAPWTDate']; echo date("Y-m-d",strtotime($datetime1));?>">
</div>
```

I also tried "m-d-Y", "mm-dd-YYYY" but to no avail. I really don't know what to do now.

When I tried to use single # on the beginning and the end, my code will be like this
[image]

Comment: You probably need to put `#txtAPWTDate#` in quotes.

Comment: I also did that '#txtAPWTDate#', and when I did the sql statement doesn't work anymore. I also tried '#'txtAPWTDate'#', not working as well.

Comment: can you include a couple of lines around your statement? I think you are missing something, but more code is needed to be able to figure it out...

Comment: @JoSSte done adding some line of codes.

Comment: it is still unclear. please paste the part where you set  `$sql = ... ;`

Comment: you are missing a `$`  I would expect that `$sql = "UPDATE tblAudPlan SET tblAudPlan.[WTDate] = #$txtAPWTDate# WHERE tblAUdPlan.[AudPlanNo] = '$txtAPNo'";` would work. or maybe `$sql = "UPDATE tblAudPlan SET tblAudPlan.[WTDate] = '#$txtAPWTDate#' WHERE tblAUdPlan.[AudPlanNo] = '$txtAPNo'";`

Comment: Hi @JoSSte Apologies, I just forgot to type the $ before sql. However, on my code $ is included.

Comment: did you see the other two changes i suggest in my comment?

Comment: @JoSSte ah yes, i tried #txtAPWDate# and '#$txtAPWTDate#' both are not working. Once I use # anything that follows it are commented out.

Comment: btw  you ought to use `filter_input` instead of using `$_POST` directly...

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the SQL by double quotes

```
$sql = "UPDATE tblAudPlan SET WTDate = #$txtAPWTDate# WHERE AudPlanNo = '$txtAPNo'";
```

Comment: Yea, my SQL is wrapped by double quotes.

Comment: Did you use `$` symbol before `txtAPWTDate` var?

Comment: @Janie yes, I did.

Comment: Although I'm not sure I think the db engine deserve `mm/dd/yyyy` date format.

Comment: @Janie I did remove the $ symbol and something inserted. I tried 07/14/2019 as an example, but the value inserted is 21/05/1905. I tried editing the format to m-d-Y, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I have experimented a little bit, to clarify this in my head:

I wrote a tiny script to test;

```
<?php

$alpha   = "myvar";
$bravo   = "UPDATE myTable SET mycol='#$alpha#' WHERE a = 1";
$charlie = "UPDATE myTable SET mycol=#$alpha#   WHERE a = 1";
$delta   = <<< EOT
UPDATE myTable SET mycol=#$alpha#  WHERE a = 1
EOT;


echo "a:\n";
echo $alpha;
echo "\n";

echo "b:\n";
echo $bravo;
echo "\n";

echo "c:\n";
echo $charlie;
echo "\n";
echo "d:\n";
echo $delta;
echo "\n";
```

... which I then ran on the command line using `php test.php`

Resulting in the following:

```
a:
myvar
b:
UPDATE myTable SET mycol='#myvar#' WHERE a = 1
c:
UPDATE myTable SET mycol=#myvar#   WHERE a = 1
d:
UPDATE myTable SET mycol=#myvar#  WHERE a = 1
```

Which means that my and @MH2K9's suggestion of writing 
`$sql = "UPDATE tblAudPlan SET WTDate = #$txtAPWTDate# WHERE AudPlanNo = '$txtAPNo'";`

*should* work.

If your script sees it as a comment, then You must have an intermediary step parsing $sql as php code, otherwise it is only interpereted as a string...

My php version:

> PHP 7.0.33-0+deb9u1 (cli) (built: Dec  7 2018 11:36:49) ( NTS )
>   Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
>   Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
>       with Zend OPcache v7.0.33-0+deb9u1, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies

Comment: Hi @JoSSte, may I know what do you mean by I have an intermediary step parsing? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I meant that the only situation a `#` inside a string will give you grief is if you are using that string inside a call to `eval` [See the manual entry for eval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php)

Comment: Got it, Thanks, JoSSTe, i'll give this a +1.